# How does the Kodaly rhythm method handle rests?

Tags: practice, rhythm, rests

I am intrigued by the simplicity of Kodaly's 'rhythmic imitation' method which supports the lyric flow.

And, I have been investigating how Kodaly would have equally imitated the 'rest' values with the same precision, so as to emphasize the length of any 'rest' distinct from a lyric syllable.

Is there a specific imitative approach to help control the length of the 'silence' (without counting)? The structured use of syllables is far more precise than saying 'and', for example.

So, if the lyric rhythm is imitated by TE KE TI TI followed by an eighth 'silence', my question is "what rhythm syllable(s) would Kodaly have perhaps used in this case"?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I grew up with this method, and our teacher never used different syllables for different rests.  When we were very young, we used "sh" as a quarter rest.  If we had more quarter rests we just added more *sh*'s.  Over time though, we were taught to internalize the rest.  I think the idea is that silence is the "default."  So, to answer your question, I suppose you could just pick a rest duration that is sufficiently short for your purpose, and replicate the method.